# window.onload event not working in a <script> which is generated at window.onload

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I am dynamically creating and appending a new `<script>` to the DOM, after the window has loaded:

```
const loadDynamicScript = () => {

  const dynamicScript = document.createElement('script');
  dynamicScript.src = '/my-dynamic-script.js';
  document.body.appendChild(dynamicScript);
}

window.addEventListener('load', loadDynamicScript);
```

> **N.B.** I have tried `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadDynamicScript);` but this means `/my-dynamic-script.js` loads too soon.

Unexpectedly, any `window.onload` event listener in `my-dynamic-script.js` doesn't work now.

I am guessing this is because the event listener listens for the single specific moment at which the `window` loads and *any time after that* is too late. (This is different from what I anticipated - that once the window had loaded, the window would be in a state which would always positively trigger a `window.onload` event listener).

So, inside `my-dynamic-script.js`... what can I use instead of:

```
window.addEventListener('load', activateMyFunction);
```

I have tried:

- `self.addEventListener('load', activateMyFunction);`
- `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', activateMyFunction);`
- `window.addEventListener('pageshow', activateMyFunction);`
- `document.body.addEventListener("pageshow", myFunction);`

So far no luck. I obviously need to be more creative.

---

One solution that ***has*** worked is simply removing the function invocation from the event listener and declaring it without adornment:

```
myFunction();
```

But this isn't ideal. I'd really prefer to invoke any function within some kind of event listener (or similar).

Comment: Could you explain as to *why* you would want to wait to listen for an event that has already passed? Does your code rely on being invoked when the page is in a specific state?

Comment: Yes, I can explain. `my-dynamic-script.js` is compiled from sanitised third-party input and I cannot rule out that it will not contain `window.onload` event listeners. I need to parse and replace.

Comment: I second @EmielZuurbier. You're right that the onload event is a specific trigger and not an ongoing condition, but what you're doing seems to defy that understanding -- the fact that the dynamic script is executing is evidence that the window has loaded. If you really want to double-check, maybe wrap your invocation in a check for [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe re-fire the onload event manually once the dynamic script loads by using `dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));` ?

Comment: Thanks @Declan. As you and Emiel were writing your comments I also discovered `document.readyState === 'complete'` over at https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded - you're right, that could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, @Artur - yes, CTS_AE's **Deeper Example** answer on the question you have referenced is the best solution I have seen.

Comment: Thank you, @Emiel for your answer below. I didn't see it before re-classifying this question as a duplicate, else I would have commented underneath it. Your `window.dispatchEvent` is a good solution.

Comment: You're welcome, but thank @declan-mckelvey-hembree for the idea. Have a nice day!

Comment: Tis a pleasure.

Comment: I've put together a definitive solution for when `window.addEventListener('load', activateMyFunction);` & `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', activateMyFunction);` don't work: it requires a single character substitution (eg. from `window.addEventListener('load', activateMyFunction);` to `window_addEventListener('load', activateMyFunction);`). The function `window_addEventListener` looks like this: `const window_addEventListener = (eventName, callback, useCapture = false) => {if ((document.readyState === 'interactive') || (document.readyState === 'complete')) {callback();}}`.

Answer (score 3):

As @declan-mckelvey-hembree suggested manually dispatch the `load` event on the window object again.

Add an event listener to the `script` tag to know when the file has been loaded. When it has use `window.dispatchEvent` to manually fire `load` on `window`.

Be sure to add `{once: true}` as the third parameter on your `load` event listener that calls the `loadDynamicScript` function. Otherwise that function will be called as well when you dispatch the `load` event.

```
const loadDynamicScript = () => {
  const dynamicScript = document.createElement('script');

  // Wait for script to load.
  script.addEventListener('load', () => { 

    // Dispatch 'load' event from window to trigger 'load' event
    // listeners in '/my-dynamic-script.js' file.
    const loadEvent = new Event('load');
    window.dispatchEvent(loadEvent); 
  }

  dynamicScript.src = '/my-dynamic-script.js';
  document.body.appendChild(dynamicScript);
}

// Adding {once: true} prevents loadDynamicScript from firing again on load.
// Otherwise the scripts would be added infinitely.
window.addEventListener('load', loadDynamicScript, {once: true);
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was envisioning, thanks for writing it out!